# How to exit from application which is setted as home app at manifest

Tags: android, default, exit, home-button

I setted my android app as Home in android manifest with following code. But i want to exit from this app when i want but it reopens itself. Is it possible to exit from application and prevent auto re-open until i want to open manually or pressing home button myself. Is it possible to do this.

```
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Answer (score 0):

that isn't possible. by pressing the home button all applications using "android.intent.category.HOME" will be displayed to choose from. when the user pick one to always be picked for home button, then the behaviour you descriped will happen. so the only choice you/or rather the user of your application has, is to noch set an application to always open when asked to do so.

Comment: No, that is not the only choice.  To unset a default home app, enter settings, applications, select the current home app, and clear its defaults.  At an extreme, boot the device in safe mode first.

Comment: sure, the result is the same though (not picking a default home app). Sorry i wasn't clear about what i was trying to say :D

Comment: No - *unpicking* a default **after having had the benefit of having one set** is quite different from not picking it in the first place, and being unable to enjoy that benefit.

Comment: is there any way to switch it on/off ?